# Show a form and hide another doesn't work in IE

Tags: jquery, forms, internet-explorer, show-hide

all i want is to show a form while i hide another.
I've tried .toggle(), .hide(), .show(), .css(display), etc.

All i know is that it works perfectly in FF, and not in IE, but when i comment one of the lines, it works for the other. The original code was:

```
$('#form_registro_men').hide();
$('#form_registro_adul').show();
```

As simple as that. I have also tried a setTimeOut with the second code line, and it doesn't work neither.
Any idea of how, at least, to solve the problem??? Thanks a lot!!!:)

Adding some og the HTML

```
 <form method="post" action="./framework/Registro" class="form_registro" id="form_registro_men"  style="display: block">
        <fieldset id='camp_obl'>
                    ......
```

```
<form method="post" action="./framework/Registro"  class="form_registro" id="form_registro_adul" style="display: none">
    <fieldset id='camp_obl'>
        .....
</form>
```

Those are the two forms, i am trying to hide the first and show the second, of viceversa.

Comment: Hi, could you post a sample of your html please?

Comment: lol I hope you got your IE options javascript enabled to start with, these all API work in all the browsers, anyhow HTML will be awesome B-)

Comment: I know i have it, when i comment one of the two Jquery lines, the one i leaver works. It shows or hides the form... but i can't do both things:S

Comment: first of all, you can't use the same id on those two fieldsets.

Comment: Yes but, no, it still doesn't work. I've checked all the ids, all are different, and still IE simply blocks and i must close it and open it to continue working:S

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved somehow... i just added a div before each form and showed and hided them... i don't know if it's the best solution... and still don't know why it didn't work with the forms, but at least i can continue working :S